# How do i develop a plug-in for nestjs application?

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, plugins, nestjs

How to import a nestjs Library in nestjs application at production mode?

I am already try to make lazy loading for Js library but outcome is empty object.

Comment: Could you add a bit of code, even pseudo-code, around what you're trying to do?

Comment: In visual studio code if I want to add some features to app I am using and install extensions.

Comment: I want to use this design pattern in nestjs application

Comment: Nest doesn't easily have this capability. [I've implemented something inside of `nest-commander` for plugins, but make sure you understand how it works before just using it](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nest-commander/blob/main/packages/nest-commander/src/command.factory.ts#L31)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.